# How to use printf so that zeros are printed with decimals

Tags: c, printf, double, decimal, stdio

I'm running a simple calculation in C, for which, sometimes, the result is exactly 0. I then print these results using something like `printf("%0.4g", result)`. If the result is not 0, it does what I want it do, e.g., the output may be `1.796e+04`. However, if the result is exactly 0, which it often is, the output will be `0`.

My question is, what can I do to print `0.0000`, with 4 decimals, even though the number there might be exactly 0?

Comment: Does 5 spaces with a "0" is acceptable? ie. `"    0"` (comments merge spaces, so I can't write it)

Comment: when it is 0 you want to show 0.000 ?

Comment: When the result is 1.0E-6, what do you see (hope to see)?  IIRC, `%g` strips trailing zeros by default.  But POSIX says _Finally, unless the '#' flag is used, any trailing zeros shall be removed from the fractional portion of the result and the decimal-point character shall be removed if there is no fractional portion remaining._  So `"%#0.4g"` should do the job.

Comment: The specifier `%0.4g` specifies to have the number with 3 decimal places, ie. `1.746e+04`. To have `0.0000` with 4 decimal places you need to use `.5g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the statement

`printf("%0.4e\n", res);`

might solve your problem!

Comment: perfect, this does exactly as I wanted, I now get 0.0000e+00, which is even better than what I was asking for! Now when I print multiple results in-a-row, everything looks aligned and clean.

Answer (score 3):

To have 4 decimals, you have to specify `.5`. To have `0` print as `0.0`, you have to add `#`.

```
printf("%#.5g", 0.0);
```

Note that this will print `4` decimal places, unlike `%0.4g`, that will print 3 decimal places.

The `0` before the dot `.` is unneeded. It is used to specify, that the field should be prefixed with zeros not with spaces when matching a field length. But you don't specify the field length, so no prefixing takes place, so the `0` can be left out.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `%g` format with the `#` modifier probably does what you want.

The POSIX specification for [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) (which is generally a superset of C11 [§7.21.6.1 The `printf()` function](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1), but here POSIX says the same as C11) requires:

> - `g`, `G` — The **double** argument representing a floating-point number shall be converted in the style `f` or `e` (or in the style `F` or `E` in the case of a `G` conversion specifier), depending on the value converted and the precision. Let `P` equal the precision if non-zero, 6 if the precision is omitted, or 1 if the precision is zero. Then, if a conversion with style `E` would have an exponent of `X`:
>
>   - If `P > X >= -4`, the conversion shall be with style `f` (or `F`) and precision `P-(X+1)`.
>   - Otherwise, the conversion shall be with style `e` (or `E`) and precision `P -1`.
>
> Finally, unless the '`#`' flag is used, any trailing zeros shall be removed from the fractional portion of the result and the decimal-point character shall be removed if there is no fractional portion remaining.
>
> A **double** argument representing an infinity or NaN shall be converted in the style of an `f` or `F` conversion specifier.

So, the trailing zeroes you want are retained by specifying `#` in the conversion specification — `"%#0.4g"`.

If you want 4 digits after the decimal point though, you need to use `"%#0.5g"`.

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double data[] = { 0.0, -0.0000001, +1.234E-6, 1.796e+04, 3.14159265, 6.022140857E+23, 6.62607004E-34 };
    enum { NUM_DATA = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]) };
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_DATA; i++)
        printf("%20.10g = %#0.4g\n", data[i], data[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output (Mac running macOS 10.14.4 Mojave — home-built GCC 9.1.0 compiler):

```
                   0 = 0.000
              -1e-07 = -1.000e-07
           1.234e-06 = 1.234e-06
               17960 = 1.796e+04
          3.14159265 = 3.142
     6.022140857e+23 = 6.022e+23
      6.62607004e-34 = 6.626e-34
```

You do recognize approximations to Planck's Constant and Avogadro's Number, don't you?

Comment: yes, this is a very good solution, and does exactly what I was asking for. However, someone else pointed out using %0.4e, which isn't what I was asking for specifically, but I like this method even better. Thank you though.

Comment: and no, I didn't notice the old 6.022e23, I do now!

Answer (score 1):

You can use
  `printf("%0.4f",YourVeriable);`

Comment: How does that produce `1.796e+04`?